# Finding a (nonidentity) rational map of the plane with period $7$

Tags: rational-functions, function-and-relation-composition

> Does there exist a nonidentity (which also is not  a  rotation) rational map $f:\mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ with period $7$, i.e., for which the seventh iteration $f^7$ is the identity map?

I know such a function, $f:(x,y)\mapsto \left(\frac{1}{y},x(1+y)\right)$, with period $5$. Here is a verification done in Maple:

```
f :=  (x, y) ->( 1/y, x*(1+y));
(f@@5)(x, y);
```

$$\left( {\frac {1+x \left( 1+y \right) }{y} \left( 1+{\frac {1}{x \left( 1+y
 \right) } \left( 1+{\frac {1+x \left( 1+y \right) }{y}} \right) }
 \right) ^{-1}}
 \right. ,$$ $$\left.{x \left( 1+y \right)  \left( 1+{\frac {y}{1+x \left( 1+y \right) }
 \left( 1+{\frac {1}{x \left( 1+y \right) } \left( 1+{\frac {1+x
 \left( 1+y \right) }{y}} \right) } \right) } \right)  \left( 1+{
\frac {1+x \left( 1+y \right) }{y}} \right) ^{-1}}\right)
$$

```
simplify((f@@5)(x, y)[1]),simplify((f@@5)(x, y)[2]);
```

$$ x,\,y$$

Comment: @Ihf : Do rational functions under composition form a group?

Comment: @user64494 Certainly not, the zero function has no inverse.

Comment: @Ihf : For example, see [that](http://archive.numdam.org/ARCHIVE/ASENS/ASENS_1983_4_16_2/ASENS_1983_4_16_2_193_0/ASENS_1983_4_16_2_193_0.pdf).

Answer (score 3):

The $2 \times 2$ rotation matrix for an (anticlockwise) rotation by $\frac{\pi}{7}$ is
$$\pmatrix{\cos \frac{\pi}{7} & -\sin \frac{\pi}{7} \\ \sin \frac{\pi}{7} & \cos \frac{\pi}{7}}.$$ Via the usual identification of that group with the group of Mobius transformations (and clearing the cosine factors for readability), the image of that matrix in $PSL(2, \Bbb R) = SL(2, \Bbb R) / \{\pm I\}$ under the canonical projection map can be identified with the rational function 
$$f_7 : t \mapsto \frac{t - \alpha}{1 + \alpha t},$$
where $$\alpha := \tan \frac{\pi}{7}.$$
Clearly $f_7 \neq \text{id}$ and via the above identification (or by repeated application of the tangent sum identity) we see that $f_7^7 = \text{id}$.

So, the rational transformation 
$$g_7 : (x, y) \mapsto (f_7(x), y)$$
is not the identity but satisfies $g_7^7 = \text{id}$.

We can produce a natural example that involves $y$ in a more essential way by replacing $t$ in the definition of $f_7$ with a complex variable $z = x + iy$ and decomposing $f_7$ into real and imaginary parts. This yields the rational map
$$h_7 : (x, y) \mapsto \left( \frac{\alpha x^2 + (1 - \alpha^2) x - \alpha + \alpha y^2}{(1 + \alpha x)^2 + \alpha^2 y^2}, \frac{(1 + \alpha^2) y}{(1 + \alpha x)^2 + \alpha^2 y^2} \right)$$
of period $7$, which can be rewritten in various ways.

Note that this construction is not specific to the number $7$. Replacing it, for example, with $3$ and using the special value $\tan \frac{\pi}{3} = \sqrt{3}$ gives the analogous maps
$$f_3 : x \mapsto \frac{x - \sqrt{3}}{1 + \sqrt{3} x}$$
and
$$h_3 : (x, y) \mapsto \left( \frac{\sqrt{3} x^2 - 2 x + \sqrt{3} y^2 - \sqrt{3}}{3x^2 + 2 \sqrt{3} x + 3 y^2 + 1} , \frac{4 y}{3x^2 + 2 \sqrt{3} x + 3 y^2 + 1} \right)$$
of period $3$.

Comment: @ Travis : Thank you for the interest to the question and your answer.. A more deep question is about the periodic rational function over the rationals. I edited my question. In any way, I voted up your answer.

Comment: @user64494 You're welcome. If you are specifically looking for a solution with components in $\Bbb Q(x, y)$, you should certainly specify that in your question.

Comment: @user64494 Seeing the edit to the original question, I think there is a misunderstanding: Neither the map $g_7$ nor $h_7$ is a rotation (we did produce our example by considering rotations as elements of $SL(2, \Bbb R)$, but the resulting Mobius transformations are not themselves rotations). By construction, $g_7^k(0, 0)=h_7^k(0, 0)=\left(-\tan \frac{k \pi}{7}, 0\right)$, and so the orbit of $(0, 0)$ under $g_7$ is $$\left\{\left(-\tan \frac{k\pi}{7},0\right):k\in\{0,\ldots,6\}\right\};$$ this is a collection of seven distinct points on the $x$-axis, and so is not the orbit of any rotation.